# text-shadow in older FireFox versions

Tags: firefox, css

I have upgraded my FireFox to 9.0.1 so I can't checked what I am asking. I want to use text-shadow css inside my site but I don't know if it works in older FireFox versions like 3.5 . box-shadow effect for FF 3.5 was -moz-box-shadow.Is it -moz-text-shadow for FF 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://caniuse.com/ to see if the browser supports it.

According to that table, `text-shadow` support was added to Firefox starting from version `3`. I'd imagine that it still had the `-moz` prefix as well, so the property should be:

```
-mox-text-shadow: ...
```